# CodeIgniter join returns last row

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I have two tables:

```
orders: 
orderid      customer_id amount
1       5           1
2       5           2
3       8           3
4       5           11
5       8           45
6       11          23
7       11          2

orders_items:
id      orderid      item    quantity
1       1           'item1'     1
2       1           'item2'     2
3       2           'item1'     1 
4       3           'item1'     3
5       3           'item2'     1 
6       3           'item3'     1
```

Now I would like to get the infomation of every order including all the different items per order.
I use:

```
 $this->db->select()->from('orders')->join('orders_items', 'orders.orderid = orders_items.orderid' );
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result_array = $query->result_array();
```

This however gives me the array with only the last item for every order. What am I doing wrong?
My final array should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderid] => 49
            [customerid] => 2
            [amount] => 438.00
            [id] => 63
            array(
               array(
                 [item] => Service1
                 [quantity] => 22
                 [subtotal] => 439
                    ),
               array(
                 [item] => Service2
                 [quantity] => 22
                 [subtotal] => 439
                    )
                 )
        )
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to do [foreach](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) loop like :

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: Wow you are fast. I was still editing the <pre> but you already did it. You answer does not really help me. I know that I should use a for each, but as I said I only get an array with the last service. So if I have 3 services for an order my array only contains service 3.

Comment: Okay. I understood you wrong. Sorry. I tried it and it does work! Thanks and sorry for my ignorance..